# How to perform user login from front-end in oauth2?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I've implemented the [`oauth2-server`](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server) which is awesome (but sometimes unclear) library. The problem is however, separate from oauth clients I also have users who just need to login. Do they do this with another grant then the `authorization_code`? If so which one?

Currently I'm doing this via my one-page application via a http POST request with username and password. Should i use the `password grant` for this? If so do I need to create an oauth client for my front-end application? (this just seems weird)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the oAuth authorization server supports 2 endpoints according to the spec: /authorize and /token. But if you need another capability, which is totally not related to the oAuth flow, you can add another API for that.

All other grants that you mentioned are related to different flows. The login support is not one of them.

So what I would do is add another HTTP API to support a simple login. This API get user and password (depends how you implemented your DB access - I assume that the passwords are stored in your DB encrypted, to your API should get an encrypted API as well, etc...)

BTW i have this GitHub repo https://github.com/OhadR/RESTful-login with a sample code how to perform (and use) restful login

Comment: So I should create another `/login` endpoint which can be done but what should I return from this endpoint? Is it an `JWT` or something like this? Because that is what my `OAuth2 clients` get assigned. Or should I use another system?

Comment: /login could be a good name for the endpoint. What it should return is design-dependant; e.g. it could return a token (string) that could be used for other APIs...

Comment: JWT can be one option for this, sure.

Comment: BTW i have this GitHub repo https://github.com/OhadR/RESTful-login with a sample code how to perform (and use) restful login...

feel free to mark this answer as 'accepted' (if it is)